# subdomain,testing using cucumber or capybara and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara, rspec-rails

Some part of the development of my project has been done.Our 
company asks me to write cucumber test cases for the developed code 
and for the henceforth development as well. 
The routes file have two subdomains for admin and hosts.Devise is also 
being used.

Now i installed cucumber and have written the first scenario for the 
first story when the non registerd user lands on the home page,enters 
a valid email and gets redirected to the next page..the page has no 
password field.

```
Scenario: Non registered user lands on beta home page. 
Given: I am on the homepage 
When: I enter valid email with "bahubalian...@gmail.com". 
Then: I should be redirected to request invitation page.
```

The problem is in my routes file, I have,

```
constraints :subdomain => ADMIN_SUBDOMAIN do 
  .... 
  root :to => admin#index 
end 
constraints :subdomain => HOST do 
  ... 
  root :to => home#index. 
end
```

Now how do i specify the path.rb file to look for the root_path in 
that specific subdomain. 
Theres no root_path written outside the subdomain constraints. 
This is my first time with testing.
I am really stuck onto this.Any help is deeply appreciated.

I just got to know from somebody that this can be implemented using capybara.If so ,could you please give a little idea about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out it was pretty simple.Capybara provides a default_host method.
So I just needed to mention,

```
When I visit subomain sub
```

And then the webstep

---

```
Given /^I visit subdomain (.*)$/ do |site_domain|

  site_domain = "http://sub.example.com" if site_domain == "admin"

  Capybara.default_host = site_domain
  visit "/"
end
```

---

Update:

default_host is not supposed to be used as it is not mentioned in the docs.
Instead try using absolute path in visit.

```
Given /^I visit subdomain (.*)$/ do |site_domain|

  site_domain = "http://sub.example.com" if site_domain == "admin"
  visit site_domain
end
```

Comment: Perfect, but the session doesn't work through subdomains. How can I change the cookie domain to an "all subdomain" type (.example.com)?